# c# WinForm Deserialize SOAP string to treeview control

Tags: c#, winforms, soap, treeview

I have a SOAP response like so:

```
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
  <m:GetStockPriceResponse>
    <m:Price>34.5</m:Price>
  </m:GetStockPriceResponse>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to fill this response into a winform treeView control using the following code.

```
private void DeserializeToTreeViewSoap(string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || !value.IsValidXml()) return;

    BeginUpdate();
    var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.LoadXml(value);

    Nodes.Clear();
    Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xDoc.DocumentElement.Name));

    var currentNode = Nodes[0];
    AddTreeNodeSoap(xDoc.DocumentElement, currentNode);
    EndUpdate();
    ExpandAll();
}

private void AddTreeNodeSoap(XmlNode soapNode, TreeNode treeNode)
{
    if (soapNode.HasChildNodes)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x <= soapNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1; x++)
        {
            var xNode = soapNode.ChildNodes[x];
            treeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
            var currentNode = treeNode.Nodes[x];
            AddTreeNodeSoap(xNode, currentNode);
        }
    }
    else
        treeNode.Text = soapNode.OuterXml.Trim();
}
```

My Problem is that I lose the following information:

```
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock"
```

This is because the XmlNode.Name property does not contain this information and I'm using the name to create the Nodes.

I can't see another property in XmlNode which contains the missing information.

How do I create a node including the information?